# Is it possible to check what can be imported from npm module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Does npm or any other utility provide a list of what modules are exposed by a package? For example I'm getting started with React, from a skeleton they provided `{ Component }`, but from some GitHub boilerplates I see many other modules importable from react. Is there a general way for listing out the available modules?

Comment: `console.log(require('some-module'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> first require or import module

```
 import {Participant} from '../../file';
```

or

```
import {Participant};
```

> then check before use what is imported

```
console.log('module : ', Participant)
```